# How to add AES-GCM support for Tomcat 7 running in Java 7

Tags: java, tomcat, aes-gcm

I'm well aware that Java 7 by default doesn't support GCM based ciphers. Therefore I have tried to get it done via Bouncy Castle.

I have the following ciphers configured in my Tomcat's HTTPS connector:

> ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,**TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256**"

And I have placed *bcprov-jdk15on-156.jar* in jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/ext.

Also have added the following property to jdk1.7.0_80/jre/lib/security/java.security

> security.provider.1=org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider

When GCM ciphers are configured in the Tomcat connector, clients cannot connect to my server at all. Seems configuring Bouncy Castle has no effect at all.

Is there anyway I can make this working? Any other JCE provider that I could use maybe?

NOTE: I'm using Oracle JDK 1.7.0_80. It is not possible to migrate to Java 8.

Comment: Do you have any errors in Tomcat, during start or client  connection?

Comment: @SlawomirJaranowski nope, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle Java JDK some strength of cryptography is limited.

Please install:
Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy is already added. It won't have any effect on the GCM ciphers in Java 7